# Is it past tense or present tense after the word "could"?

Tags: tenses, could

1. There is yet a law that regulates it, which then could backfire and put him in danger.
2. There is yet a law that regulates it, which then could backfired and put him in danger.

Comment: Example 1. is not present tense. It's the infinitive form (which is identical to present tense for regular verbs). Infinitives are not inflected.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is correct. Modal verbs (could/would) are followed by the bare infinitive of the verb (without the "to" particle) in this type of construction.

"All the MODAL VERBS except ”ought, dare and need, to be to, to have to” are followed by the Infinitive without particle to (a bare - Infinitive)."

library.ziyonet.uz/ru/book/download/87054